# Disable DatePicker changing year by scrolling months

Tags: android, android-studio, datepicker

I have a DatePicker and the issue I'm encountering is that going from december to january is possible, but I want to only display 12 values for the months, from January to December, without the possibility to change year from the month part of the datepicker.

[image: 1]

You can see on the above image what I'm talking about if I'm not clear enough. Here I can go from janv. (january) to december, and the year will change to 2021. How can I disable this functionality ? Thank you in advance!

Here's how I define my DatePicker :

```
<DatePicker
    android:id="@+id/date_input"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:calendarViewShown="false"
    android:datePickerMode="spinner"/>
```

Comment: May use 3 separate NumberPicker to make a custom layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have developed below logic to stop **auto scroll year** when we jump from January to December or December to January

```
val savedMonthOfYear = 0
val savedYear = 0

date_input.setOnDateChangedListener { view, year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth ->
            if ((savedMonthOfYear == 0 && monthOfYear == 11) || (savedMonthOfYear == 11 && monthOfYear == 0)) {
                if (savedYear != year) {
                    date_input.updateDate(savedYear, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth)
                }
            } else {
                savedYear = year
            }
            savedMonthOfYear = monthOfYear
        }
```

Comment: What are those `savedMonthOfYear` and `savedYear` ? I can't test your code right now but it seems to me that I would get an `undefined` error.  If so, could you tell me how you get those variables ? Thanks

Comment: Oops it's local variables, I have edited my answer can you please test now. It's working in my code

Comment: I have updated code, Can  you please try again? @Stephane